# Issue with icanhaz

Tags: jquery, jsp, icanhaz.js, jsp-fragments

I have the following code saved in a .jspf file:

```
<!-- include library files -->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="icanhaz.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="user">
Hello my name is {{ name }}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    user_data_object = {name: "Michael"};

    <!-- 
        This should set user to the string 'Hello my name is Michael'.
        However, ich.user is undefined, so when I make this call, I get the error:

           TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function 
                   (evaluating 'ich.user(user_data_object)'
    -->
    var user = ich.user(user_data_object);
    });

</script>
```

Why isn't this working? I tested to make sure jQuery and ich are being correctly included and they are. If I throw this code in a .html file on my computer, it works. However, once I throw it on my server in a .jspf file, it stops working. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the server set up to deliver `.jspf` files?

Comment: yes, it is. The page is being delivered, and my browser is receiving all the code you see above.

Comment: What version of icanhaz and jquery are you using?  I tried your code with: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js and https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ICanHaz.js/0.10.3/ICanHaz.min.js and it worked fine.